Why does `perf report` show multiple functions at top-level?
I'm new to perf and I'm struggling to interpret the output from perf report. I've written a tiny string-splitter benchmark in Zig (which is just like C when compiled) and collected some CPU profiles (call graphs). I used the command perf record -g -- ./my_binary. I verified the contents of the perf.data file, and all I see are samples that look like this:
str_split   22826 72307.539293:   10101010 cpu-clock:ppp: 
                  25d7e0 str_split.Delimiter.find+0x5b0 (/zig/str_split)
                  25d72b str_split.Delimiter.find+0x4fb (/zig/str_split)
                  2343ac str_split.SplitIterator.next+0x5c (/zig/str_split)
                  231604 str_split.BM_strSplit+0xb0 (/zig/str_split)
                  230f80 str_split.benchmark+0x2c0 (/zig/str_split)
                  2316e8 str_split.main+0x64 (/zig/str_split)
                  230c0c start.posixCallMainAndExit+0x458 (/zig/str_split)
                       0 [unknown] ([unknown])

Note that every single event starts with posixCallMainAndExit at the top of the call graph. However, when I run perf report, I see this:
+  100.00%     0.00%  str_split  [unknown]         [.] 0000000000000000
+  100.00%     0.00%  str_split  str_split         [.] start.posixCallMainAndExit
+  100.00%     0.00%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.main
+  100.00%     0.00%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.benchmark
+  100.00%     0.77%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.BM_strSplit
+   97.68%    12.16%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.SplitIterator.next
+   80.12%    16.80%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.Delimiter.find
+   63.32%     2.32%  str_split  str_split         [.] mem.indexOfAny__anon_8477
+   61.00%    61.00%  str_split  str_split         [.] mem.indexOfAnyPos__anon_8721
+    5.41%     5.41%  str_split  str_split         [.] str_split.Predicate.check
+    1.54%     1.54%  str_split  str_split         [.] mem.doNotOptimizeAway__anon_4091

Is there a way to tell perf report to show a tree where posixCallMainAndExit is at the top? Why is it showing me all functions?

There's initialization code that sets up whatever zig programs need to run  and then calls posixCallMainAndExit
